# I don't understand why we represent functions $f:I \subseteq \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ the way we do.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, parametrization

I don't understand why we represent functions $f:I \subseteq \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ the way we do: doing an analogy with how we represent functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ or from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, my impression would be to represent functions like $f$ in the format: $$(t,f_1(t),f_2(t))$$

But instead we grab all the points $(f_1(t),f_2(t))$, that is, the image of $f$ and we plot that in $\Bbb R^2$, and we call $f$ a parametrization.

As an example of this, let $f(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$. If we represented this by plotting the points $(t,\cos t, \sin t)$ we'd get a helix. But instead we 'splash' that helix into the wall and we get the parametrization of a circle.

Comment: Here is my **guess**: Sometimes we want to look at the output of a function when the input is implicit. For example, in real life if you drop a drop of food coloring into a glass of still water and watch the color disperse, in some sense you are watching the output of the function that models the density of the color at each position in the water.  The input, time, is changing, but there is no time axis (which would require the fourth dimension).  Instead, you are looking at the function of color density which is parameterized by time.

Comment: But the truth is I don't know what I'm talking about so the above comment could be worthless.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Perhaps you are confusing functions with curves. What you describe is a curve in $\mathbb R^2$, not a function $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: What do you mean, @TonyK? $\alpha(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ is a function, and it's image describes a curve in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yes. And you are right that this image is not a function. The reason for this is that paper and computer screens are two-dimensional. But then...what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not "represent" functions $f:I \subseteq \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ as $(f_1(t),f_2(t))$.

The functions $f:I \subseteq \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ are represented as $(t,f_1(t),f_2(t))$ (where $t$ varies on some subset of real line) just like other kinds of functions.

$(f_1(t),f_2(t))$ (where $t$ varies on some subset of real line) is the set which is called the *image* of function $f$.

Image of a function is an important concept, but "image of a function" ($(f_1(t),f_2(t))$ over varying $t$) and "graph of a function" ($(t,f_1(t),f_2(t))$ over varying $t$) are two different concepts. You should just understand that both these two: a. exist; b. are important; c. are different.

Comment: Also note that for 1-argument functions the image is usually just an interval on the real line, not an interesting set. For this reason interesting images (such as parametric curves) usually appear for 2-argument (or more arguments) functions. This was the exact reason of your confusion, when you switched from 1-argument to 2-argument functions

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a useful simplification sometimes. Explicit time dependence is really scary, actually. Imagine I'm watching a system that shouldn't depend explicitly on time (earth's gravitational field shouldn't fluctuate based on time, for example). But I'm watching a ball travel and its position does depend on time. If the ball is at position $(x,y)$ at time $t_1$ and again at time $t_2$ I want to say that the ball is orbiting.

But if I imagine the ball's coordinates as having a time component, the it will never hit the same point twice. That is $(t_1,x,y) \neq (t_2,x,y)$. So the ball would never really be in orbit.

This idea is strongly reflected in the field of differential equations, where systems that do not explicitly depend on time are much better understand than those that do. Things like poincare-bendixon theorem (which are awesome) depend heavily on the notion of orbits. "If a ball hits the same point twice its path must be periodic" is a critical lemma for the theorem.